# working with a map of hibernate session factories in a spring transaction system

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

i am doing an upgrade to an existing system running postgres.

the previous architect felt that the best way to get improved performance out of the system was after each year to move the previous years data to a new schema in the database rather than simply indexing the primary schema.  (seriously, zero indexes, 9 identical schemas).

now for the problem.  ive stripped out the insane database connection logic they were using (it looked like they were trying to build a transaction manager from scratch) and replaced it with Spring Transactions.  so now im forced to deal with loops like this:

```
for(archive a : yearsArchived){
  session s = sessionfactorymap.get(a).getcurrentsession();
  (find data and copy to temporary table for report)
}
```

i can create the various session factories for the different schemas easy enough, the problem is associating them to a transaction manager so they can open the session.  when i have everything converted i get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:685)
    at parity.model.ReportThread.generate(ReportThread.java:47)
    at parity.model.ReportThread.run(ReportThread.java:31)
```

(yes, i know, it is a multi-threaded web app, previous developers were retards)

in my normal spring transaction classes i don't need to set a currentsession context because im assuming its done by the spring transaction manager.  how in the world do i fix this mess?

Comment: Are you using annotation based approach? Provide the section of your application context where you defined the sessionfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `HibernateTransactionManager` doesn't support your case out of the box, because it can only manage a single `SessionFactory`.

So, you can have different transaction managers for different session factories, but then they cannot participate in the same transaction. If it's okay, see [10.5.6.2 Multiple Transaction Managers with @Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional).

Otherwise, perhaps the easiest way to make your `SessionFactories` participate in a single transaction is to use `JTATransactionManager` with some standalone JTA implementation ([Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/), [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home), [JOTM](http://jotm.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome)).

Also, note the concept of *1PC Optimization*. I think JTA implementation should be able to apply it in your case in order to reduce overhead introduced by JTA.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info guys.  i ended up solving it by detaching those sessionfactories from the transaction manager and managing the transactions manually.  bit more effort but it works.

thanks